# Using tio.run, how does this C function return a value?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

I'd like to shorten my answer below by applying this tio.run technique from this [C example](https://tio.run/##bci9CoMwEADg3ccQhDtNqLHdjvRJuhwpsYJ/nA5XxFdvunRrvvELtg8hJTFMERSPuAiwF6@1EltLKNa/3uuyA1faOMMXxbuS@lstjaMzTTzMgEdRrDLMe4Syej7m0kRwiPSXXS6vuXRtftvsd78/0yfEkfst2XH6Ag).

Here's their C example

**Code**

```
r,a;f(x){for(a=r=x*x;a--;)r-=hypot(a%x+1,a/x)>x;x=4*r+1;}
```

**Footer**

```
main(){

printf("%d\n",f(1));
printf("%d\n",f(2));
printf("%d\n",f(3));
printf("%d\n",f(10));
printf("%d\n",f(1000));
printf("%d\n",f(2000));
}
```

but I don't understand how the result is returned from the f() function?

Here's my C code below and I'd like to remove the `main`, `return`, `printf` and just reduce it to the bare minimum bytes using their footer technique etc.,... also, @qwr noted

> I think meta consensus is that you can write a function instead of a
> whole program.

Thanks.

## C (gcc), 116 bytes

```
a,x,y;c(r){for(x=-r;x<=r;x++)for(y=-r;y<=r;a+=x*x+y*y<=r*r,y++);return a;}main(r){scanf("%u",&r);printf("%d",c(r));}
```

**How it works**

This inefficient method draws a square around the circle then iterates through all lattice points \$(x,y)\$ within it and checking if \$x^2+y^2 \le r^2 \$.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY3bCsIwEER/RQJKrtA@r/mYZTWloFG2LSZIf921@zJwDsMMpYlIBGOLHciy@5YX25YTQ7vmI0JwarqargZDbr6F7pU8x340gO/rxvWEsD9xrjqzENZizXkz8cIO3jzXVflmot442EXGYRh/VB44LZI@fw)

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106067/85334

Comment: Seems any return variable will  do, so it does not have to match the argument passed to the function, in my case r. Here's a sample `c,x,y;f(r){c=0;for(x=-r;x<=r;x++){for(y=-r;y<=r;y++){if(x*x+y*y<=r*r){c++;}}}x=c;}` and notice the x=c; returns the value, so doing r=c; was not required.

Answer (score 0):

[@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat) reduced it from 116 to 68 bytes.

## C (gcc), 68 bytes

```
a,x,y;c(r){a=0;for(x=~r;x++<r;)for(y=~r;y++<r;)a+=x*x+y*y<=r*r;x=a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3NCsIwEITvPoUUhPwVUj1u8yZelpWUgkZZCyaU9tEbLXqzOX7fzDBUd0Q5o4kmAQmWIzoL/s4iupkhat0yyJXTyunLqF1UUSeVWsfqU3MIU75hH4Qcd/sH92HwojpczqEyJBop4d8eN@1p0za2oG0xKJz@FlNeyF@xe@b69QY)